# Why exp(x) is defined rather than proved in section 6.14 of Tom Apostol's calculus Vol 1

Tags: calculus, logarithms

In section $6.12$, the exponential function is defined as:

"For any real $x$, we define $E(x)$ to be that number $y$ whose logarithm is $x$. That is, $y = E(x)$ means that $L(y) = x$.". $L(y)$ is the natural logarithm of $y$.

In section $6.13$ Tom Apostol **proved** that $E(r) = e^r$ for every rational number $r$. Then, in section $6.14$ he **defined** $e^x = E(x)$ for every real $x$.

My question is why did he decide to define $e^x$ for all real numbers, rather than prove it from the definition of the logarithm he gave in section $6.3$ and the number $e$ he gave in section $6.5$?

I am surprised, because of the tight relationship between the logarithm and the exponential, so it seems dangerous to me to define them "independently".

Comment: What is $E$? Not everyone has the book you are citing, so please, add as much context as is needed into the question so that we can help with the answer.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that. I thought that the book is freely available online, and everyone has access to it.

Comment: Even if the book is freely available online, you should, at the very least, provide a link to it. But again, you should not expect people to read a whole book just to answer one question, so it is better to try and make the question itself as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Before you can prove this equals that you need definitions of this and that. What _definition_ do you have in mind for $e^x$, for irrational $x$?

Comment: There is something to be *proved* about $E(x)$ and $e^x$, namely that they agree for all rational $x$ and that $E(x)$ makes sense as defined (for all real numbers).  Other authors do take a different approach to defining the exponential function (see Rudin's opening section in *Real and Complex Analysis*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why did he decide to define $e^x$ for all real numbers, rather than prove it from the definition of the logarithm he gave in section $6.3$ and the number $e$ he gave in section $6.5$?

Because at that point, $e^x$ is not defined for irrational numbers, so the author had nothing to prove.

---

At the point when $e^x$ is defined, the author only defined $a^b$ for **rational** values of $b$, while the value is not defined for irrational values of $b$.

If I produce a **new** definition of $e^x$ and claim that this new definition is a definition for all real values, I need to verify that the new definition is consistent with existing definitions. That means I need to prove that, for rational values of $x$, the value $E(x)$ is equal to $e^x$, where $e^x$ is defined using roots and multiplications.

For irrational values, there hasn't yet been any definition of what $e^x$ is, so we are, at that point, completely free to define $e^x$ as whatever we want.

---

Looking at it from a different perspective, the answer to your question is really simple: *It is because definitions are not something you prove*.

Comment: But he could show that $\lim_{r \to x, r \in \mathbb Q}e^r$ exists and equals $E(x)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Why **should** he do that? Even if that limit does not exist, or does not equal $E(x)$, the definition of $e^x$ is still perfectly valid. Also, the way Apostol goes about defining things, the existence of that limit is trivial, because at that point, we already know that $e^r=E(r)$, and that $E$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Of course the definition is okay. The provable fact that $e^r = E(r)$ for rational $r$ can serve as a motivation for his definition. But nevertheless he must prove that $e^x$ (or equivalently $E(x)$) is continuous resp. differentiable. Otherwise the definition wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @PaulFrost sure, but my point is that by that point in the book, $E$ is already known to be continuous.

Comment: Looking at the book now again, I don't see the explicit definition for rational exponents either. There is a power function definition on page 54 and an implicit definition of nth-root on page 147, but nth-root was used even before page 147 (e.g. example 5 on page 135). So probably the definition in rational-power case was obvious enough not to make it explicit, but the irrational-power case is more complicated, so it needed an explicit definition (or explicit connection to the exponential definition on page 242).

Comment: @S11n Look at "Introduction 3.14 Roots of higher order. Rational powers" on p. 30.

Comment: Thank you, Paul!

Answer (score -1):

In Apostol's book, the logarithm is defined as $\displaystyle
L(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1t \, dt$, and the exponential is defined as its inverse function. So, I'd say it does explore the tight relation between the two functions...

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's question. OP is aware that the function $E$ is defined as the inverse of the function $L$. They are asking why $e^x$ can be defined as $e^x=E(x)$.

Comment: @5xum At the end of the post the OP says: "I am surprised, because of the tight relationship between the logarithm and the exponential, so it seems dangerous to me to define them "independently." I'm just saying that they *are not* being defined independently.

Comment: @PierreCarre, I was surprised about something else, not about the tight relationship between the logarithm and the exponential. It seems that my confusion was that $E$ was a new exponential, and then Tom Apostol later just equated the commonly known $e^x$ to be the exponential defined in section $6.12$.